# Live Streaming video via Arduino with limited space

Tags: arduino, cameras

I am currently undertaking a competition called CanSat, in which you build a satellite in the form of a standard soda can. It will in turn then be launched 30 meters, 100 meters and then finally 500 meters into the sky. I'm stuck on something and I need a little bit of help.

Basically I am looking at streaming low quality video (480p-10fps/ 240p-30fps), using an Arduino Uno/Mega, inside of a can. The spacial limitations I mentioned above are 115 mm in height and 65 mm in diameter. I will not be able to use a conventional IP camera, due to the limitations.

I was thinking about using a Bluetooth V2 Chip in order to achieve the transfer rate to stream to a PC. **I am looking for the following help:**

1. What camera to use
2. What software to use to receive the video on a PC
3. And finally any other relevant information about the limitations of the Arduino and streaming.

Comment: You may have a hard time getting 3Mbits from the arduino required to do 480p at 10 fps. maybe 480i is possible.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ConorCurley, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I'll caution you that, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Uses): "The Bluetooth Core Specification mandates a range of not less than 10 metres (33 ft), but there is no upper limit on actual range." There's no guarantee that you'll get bluetooth to work at any distance > 10m. If you would like to *chat* more about your design problem, please join us in [chat].

Answer (score 0):

Based on your limitations, I would consider a [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3400), which has bluetooth built in. You can connect [a camera that has quite a high resolution designed to operate with the Pi](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3099) and stream the video back over whatever you choose.